# Concatenate a count for each duplicate in dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, duplicates

I want to add a concatenated count for each occurrence of a value in a dataset from query.

Example dataset:

```
ID      OtherValue    
00A     2ndValue_1    
00A     2ndValue_2    
00A     2ndValue_3    
00A     2ndValue_4    
00B     2ndValue_1    
00C     2ndValue_1    
00D     2ndValue_1    
00D     2ndValue_2
```

I wand the query to produce this dataset:

```
ID      OtherValue    ConcatinatedCount
00A     2ndValue_1    00A-001
00A     2ndValue_2    00A-002
00A     2ndValue_3    00A-003
00A     2ndValue_4    00A-004
00B     2ndValue_1    00B-001
00C     2ndValue_1    00C-001
00D     2ndValue_1    00D-001
00D     2ndValue_2    00D-002
```

I am not quite sure how to get this count per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window Functions (also called Analytics Functions or Ordered Analytics Functions) are the way to solve this.

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  OtherValue, 
  ID + '-' + FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY OtherValue), '000') as ConcatinatedCount
FROM yourtable;
```

That `ROW_NUMBER()` window-funtion will generate a row number within the partition/group of each distinct `ID` and it will order that row number by `OtherValue` within the group. Some concatenation and formatting and it should spit out what you are after.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just had to add the Right parentheses after `OtherValue`. I have been noticing Window Functions popping up more in my research. I will have to take some time to dig in to how they work.

Comment: you beat me in posting the answer jajaja

Comment: So is this the only way or simply the preferred method?

Comment: @Mike-SMT It's nearly the only way. There are some old-school ways of generating row_numbers over groups, but they are UGLY. Window Functions fill a gap in the SQL language that needed to be filled.

Comment: Ya I could not think of a SQL method of doing this. Glad to know we have an option to work around it with these Windows Functions.